# SSH fingerprint verification for Amazon AWS EC2 server with ECDSA?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fingerprint, ecdsa

When I create a new Amazon EC2 server, I connect to it using `ssh` as usual.

I see the typical warning:

```
$ ssh myserver  
The authenticity of host 'ec2-12-34-567-890.compute-1.amazonaws.com (12.34.567.890)'     can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 31:66:15:d2:19:41:2b:09:8a:8f:9f:bd:de:c6:ff:07.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

How do I verify the fingerprint before I sign in?

Ideally an answer is based on something besides the original creation console log -- because the log may get flushed out after a system restart, or during a large system installation script that generates a lot of output, or the connection is to an older system with keys that weren't tracked at creation time.

Comment: One way is to use your own keys with a known fingerprint (see: http://serverfault.com/a/581458/86472). If you control the instance (and plan for the scenario - i.e. setup the instance), getting the fingerprints on boot is easy - what you want to do with it is then up to you (e.g. publish to S3, Route53, Cloudwatch, email them, etc.). One of the easiest things would be to have a cron job run every hour that updates a tag on your instance (viewable from the console)

Comment: related question [amazon-ec2-instance-ssh-rsa-fingerprint](https://serverfault.com/questions/581367/amazon-ec2-instance-ssh-rsa-fingerprint)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Amazon EC2 console now has a web-based terminal (which presumably guarantees secure connection). Go to *Actions > Connect > EC2 Instance Connect > Connect* on *Instances* page. In the terminal, use `ssh-keygen` command to display a fingerprint of any number of host keys algorithms. The following example shows SHA-256 and MD5 fingerprints of Ed25519 hostkey:

```
sudo ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
sudo ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -E md5
```

---

*The previous answer, before the web-based terminal was introduced:*

As @joelparkerhenderson's answer covers, you can collect host key fingerprint from server's initial start log, when host keys are generated (by the `cloud-init` script):

[image]

---

If you fail to collect the keys this way, you can get them by connecting to your target instance from another trusted instance within private Amazon network, thus keeping yourself safe from man-in-the-middle attacks.

When on the trusted instance (the one you know fingerprints for) terminal, you can use following commands to collect fingerprints (`172.33.31.199` is the private IP):

```
$ ssh-keyscan 172.33.31.199 > ec2key
$ ssh-keygen -l -f ec2key
256 SHA256:oZHeiMEPLKetRgd3M5Itgwaqr2zJJH93EvSdx5UoHbQ <ip> (ED25519)
2048 SHA256:8zg105EUFFrPFpVzdfTGsgXnxuSpTiQd85k0uNapUio <ip> (RSA)
256 SHA256:L7UXLw0djE5B9W7ZhvrkYVSTZyi1MEQ2dBaRtpkkUGY <ip> (ECDSA)
```

---

If you do not have another instance, whose fingerprints you know, create new temporary instance, just for the purpose of collecting the keys. First find keys for the new temporary instance, using it's initial start log. Connect to the temporary instance from public network. Then collect keys of the target instance by connecting to it from the temporary instance, over private Amazon network. After that you can discard the temporary instance.

---

I have prepared [Guide for connecting to EC2 instance safely using WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2).

Comment: Having just used this answer (Thanks!), my first try (with a t2 instance) ended up not generating anything with `ssh-keyscan`.  Turns out that t2s launch into a VPC and I had to use a non-t2 instance to access Amazon's private network.

Answer (score 26):

Here are two solutions that worked for me during the creation of the EC2 system.

**Solution 1: Use the Amazon EC2 dashboard**

- Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com
- Tap "EC2" link.
- Tap "Instances" in the left column
- Tap the instance name you want
- Tap the select button "Actions" and choose "Get System Log" (a.k.a. "Console Output")
- In the console output, you should see the keys being generated

**Solution 2: Use the AWS EC2 command line**

You can use the `aws` command or `ec2-get-console-output` command. Both are available for download from Amazon.

To use your EC2 private key pem file, certificate pem file, region, and instance:

```
ec2-get-console-output \
  --private-key pk-ABCDEF1234567890.pem \
  --cert cert-ABCDEF1234567890.pem \
  --region us-east-1c \
  i-e706689a
```

The output shows the ssh host key fingerprints like this:

```
ec2: -----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
ec2: 1024 e0:79:1e:ba:2e:3c:71:87:2c:f5:62:2b:0d:1b:6d:7b  root@ip-10-243-118-182 (DSA)
ec2: 256 31:66:15:d2:19:41:2b:09:8a:8f:9f:bd:de:c6:ff:07  root@ip-10-243-118-182 (ECDSA)
ec2: 2048 ce:ec:3b:d3:34:3f:f3:45:76:81:9e:76:7a:d9:f5:e8  root@ip-10-243-118-182 (RSA)
ec2: -----END SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
```

The `aws` tool works similarly.

Note: these solutions only work during creation time, or when you can get the console logs. For a broader solution that works any time, see Martin's answer.

Comment: But this works only for the first run of the instance, when the log includes key generation. When you restart the instance you cannot find the fingerprints there anymore. Any other way?

Comment: @Martin Good point! Ideally Amazon can add the fingerprints as a column on the EC2 dashboard. I will add a bounty to this question to encourage people to help.

Comment: Thank you this was a tremendous help.  AWS is my first env set up ever, so being able to get at the keys via the e2c dash was much less confusing.

Comment: My keys are shown under the `BEGIN SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS` like in this answer, however, in base64. And none of them match the key shown when connecting via `ssh` (even when converted to hex). What is the problem?