# How does one verify the authenticity of an Amazon EC2 instance "host" when ssh-ing in for the first time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Normally, when using `ssh` to connect to a host for the first time, you get a message like:

```
The authenticity of host 'nova.example.com (192.168.0.63)` can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX.
```

One can then check the key fingerprint against the known fingerprint for the host to make sure you're actually connecting to the host you think you are.

I am now trying to ssh into a new Amazon EC2 instance, and I cannot find the ECDSA key fingerprint that ssh is reporting anywhere in the management console.

The one fingerprint I can find is under "￼NETWORK & SECURITY » Key Pairs", but it does not match what ssh is reporting. As far as I can tell, this is actually a fingerprint of the private key that AWS generated for me, not the host key.

Perhaps I could just say "yes" and the run "ssh-keygen -lf" on the EC2 instance, but I'm not confident that that actually protects against man in the middle attacks. (In fact, this page on [checking ssh public key fingerprints](http://www.phcomp.co.uk/Tutorials/Unix-And-Linux/ssh-check-server-fingerprint.html) suggests exactly that possibility.)

How does one correctly verify the ECDSA key fingerprint returned by ssh when connecting to an EC2 instance?

Comment: You can find the ECDSA key in the instance's log ("Get System Log" for an instance in the console). In more detail... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24773982/1428388

Comment: @jbird Thank you! I don't know how I didn't find that question/answer earlier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH fingerprint verification for Amazon AWS EC2 server with ECDSA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791219/ssh-fingerprint-verification-for-amazon-aws-ec2-server-with-ecdsa)